# WCF MaxReceivedMessageSize not being accepted

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, web-config

Trying to set MaxReceivedMessageSize in the web.config but it keeps telling me it's set to the default

InnerException = {"The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element."}

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TransportSecurity" maxReceivedMessageSize="10242880">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="10242880"/>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the service side? The client has the same setting...

Comment: Provide full or at least the endpoint tag where this binding is getting used. There can be possible that this binding not getting used and taking default values..

Comment: @nvoigt it was client side. I didn't even think of that

Answer (score 0):

issue was client side in the app.config @nvoigt

Answer (score 0):

I faced this type of issue before. I found the solution, but very strange.

I have removed the **name** attribute from **binding** tag and the **bindingConfiguration** attribute from **endpoint** tag it all worked.

This solution is also provided on - 
[Problem with large requests in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470530/problem-with-large-requests-in-wcf)

Comment: This is by design.  In WCF 4.0 and later, if you omit the name attribute from a binding configuration definition, it becomes the default binding configuration for that type of binding.  So, for example, if you set large values for maxReceivedMessageSize in a binding definition and omit the name attribute, that binding definition becomes the default for any non-explicitly defined bindings of the same type.